# Android:Compare json data with String

Tags: php, android, json

I use json to get a string data from php and i want compare this data whit a string ,even when they are equal but returns false for example

**php** file:

```
<?php
   echo "ok";
?>
```

**java** use 3 log

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
page_output = sb.toString();

Log.i("page_output",  page_output);

Log.i("page_output",  String.valueOf(page_output=="ok"));

Log.i("page_output",  String.valueOf(page_output.equals("ok")));
```

**log** out

```
07-12 03:42:45.616: I/page_output(2007): ok
07-12 03:42:45.736: I/page_output(2007): false
07-12 03:42:45.736: I/page_output(2007): false
```

you can see that `page_output` is ok but returns false

Comment: Q: Shouldn't you be using [String.equals()](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/)????

Comment: lik this `page_output.equals("ok")` but not change returns false | `Log.i("page_output",  String.valueOf(page_output.equals("ok")));` -> `07-12 03:23:35.936: I/page_output(1820): false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Log.i("page_output",  String.valueOf(page_output.trim().equals("ok")));
```

You are appending `"\n"` at the end of the every line read from your php response. So you're actually comparing `"ok\n"` with `"ok"` and that's why the comparison returns `false`.

The `trim()` function removes white spaces, including new lines `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

in this line:

> `sb.append(line + "\n");`

You add the "\n" new line character to your StringBuilder. When you call `toString` this character will also be put in your `String`.

Therefore, `page_output.equals("ok\n")` will be true.

Or you could just delete the '\n' character from the `StringBuilder` since I do not see any practical usage in your code